# spring-data both: custom repository and out of the box optionals

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm using custom Spring Data repository implementation/extension (one of the example [here](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-data/spring-data-add-custom-method-to-repository/)) but I would like to still make use of Optionals for basic operations - something as below (example for Mongo or Elasticsearch):

```
public interface DomainRepository extends MongoRepository<Domain, Long>, DomainRepositoryCustomAnyName {
    Optional<Domain> findOne(Long id);
}
```

Without the need for implemention that method on my own in my DomainRepositoryImpl class (which implements DomainRepositoryCustomAnyName).

Is that somehow possible?

Currently I'm getting an exception (the same as the one indicating that I should implement that method in my DomainRepositoryImpl  class): `Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property findOne found for type Domain`

Answer (score 3):

I ran into quite the same problem, I think. I'm not using MongoDB but PostgreSQL but the reason for the problem might be the same. The example on the site you linked to does not use `findOne` so I'm not sure where you picked that up. A lot of tutorials are for versions of spring-data prior to 2.x.x. The thing is that the interfaces and implementations of the repositories changed quite a bit from 1.11.8 to 2.0.0 so the problem of yours might be connected to a version issue.

From somewhere in the past to 1.11.8 the SimpleJpaRepository had a method

```
public T findOne(ID id)
```

and support for wrapping that result in an `Optional`. That would fit to your code. I tested it and it worked for a simple example. Of course I do not have your domain objects and so on.

In 2.0.0 this method got removed from SimpleJpaRepository and replaced by

```
public <S extends T> Optional<S> findOne(Example<S> example)
```

and

```
public Optional<T> findById(ID id)
```

So assuming that your are using spring-data-jpa 2.x.x, you have 3 options:

1. Switch back to version 1.11.8
2. Change your method signature to

   `Optional<Domain> findOne(Example<Domain> ex);`
3. Use the new method instead:

   `Optional<Domain> findById(Long id);`